# Account change address is not showing up with `getaddressesbyaccount`

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I have a tiny question regarding the Bitcoin JSON-RPC API. I have [a transaction on Testnet](http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/t/6yd81zFUCV) which sends one coin to an other address owned by me (on an other account than the sender). The sending address, `mtGaEd9zZU8B7aYSuQiDFZTo2wiS8dWb3c`, is listed under the default account, running `getaccount mtGaEd9zZU8B7aYSuQiDFZTo2wiS8dWb3c` outputs indeed an empty string. The receiving address, `mzcj8xYome3gmAWZG57yutv14sctPxbPV6`, is listed under an account named `test`, as expected running `getaccount mzcj8xYome3gmAWZG57yutv14sctPxbPV6` returns `test`. Both addresses also show up when I use `getaddressesbyaccount`, but the change that went to address `mnUJRd9CL3GV1QbWFxJxLj2DgE1ADSB8oR`, which also returns an emtpy string when using it as argument to `getaccount`, doesn't show up in the `getaddressesbyaccount` call output. Why is that? I can't sum the balances of each addresses now for a reliable account balance, only `getbalance` return the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call listreceivedbyaddress(**0, true**) to get all of your addresses (even the empty ones or those who have a zero-confirmations balance).

By default (parameterless) it will only list the addresses that contain some confirmed balance and those who have at least one confirmation for their unconfirmed balance.

Comment: I believe I was talking about `getaddressesbyaccount` not `listreceivedbyaddress`. Don't get me wrong, I'm not asking a solution (`getbalance` works just fine), I'm trying to understand why `getaddressesbyaccount` does not work.

Comment: And why would `mnUJRd9CL3GV1QbWFxJxLj2DgE1ADSB8oR` have zero confirmations? It is in the same transaction as `mzcj8xYome3gmAWZG57yutv14sctPxbPV6`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show up in the results from getaddressesbyaccount() because addresses are only associated with accounts by use of getnewaddress() or setaccount().

Comment: Why did they use this approach? It doesn't make sense to me. Also is there any other way to show all Bitcoin addresses?